# Node JS, React JS - How would an Admin Panel be able to preapprove form data from a regular user before persisting it to the database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, validation, admin

I am looking to creating an website that has a typical login and registration. When a user registers, an administrator gives this user a role of editor.

As an editor, they can populate a recipe. When they hit submit, I would like that data not to persist to the database yet, because the Administrator would like to check if is worthy for his website.

How might I create an administrator panel that does that?

Is this the best way, a panel that somehow catches the data and requires approval?

Would I require two databases? One, that has entries, and the other that has approved entries? In that database it would automatically populate the website?